# Can not set NOT NULL to column with type ARRAY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, spanned

I have a Table with column of type:

```
ARRAY<STRING(36)>
```

All data have a value, but i can not set NOT NULL.

```
ALTER TABLE Organizations ALTER COLUMN superfinUsersList ARRAY<STRING(36)> NOT NULL
```

---

```
error: Cannot add NOT NULL to column Organizations.superfinUsersList
```

Comment: I've reproduced using a new empty table and filed an internal bug on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this functionality for Arrays is not currently supported, so the error message is correct, and documentation will be updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible, you just need to make sure all your rows have some value for that column. Unfortunately the array itself can still contain null elements.